# stack exchange data dump to Oracle database?

Tags: discussion, data-dump, database

How can I import the data dump to Oracle DB? Most of the tools are done to SQL Server.

Comment: There isn't one, IIRC. Perhaps modify @SkySander's [importer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45333/fast-multi-platform-data-dump-import-sql-server-2000-2005-2008-sqlite-mysql) to support Oracle?

Comment: I can't even use SkySander's importer.. don't know where to ask

Answer (score -1):

If you can generate a CSV file you can load it onto oracle using external table or sqlloader.

Also if you have application express installed you can use that for loading data too.